# Xamarin Android SpeechRecognizer - SpeechRecognizerError.Network

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, speech-to-text

We are trying to use the speech recogniser in Xamarin on Android, we have setup the main activity like so:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IRecognitionListener
{
    TextView textMessage;

    private Button recButton;
    private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        
        // get the resources from the layout
        recButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRecord);
        textMessage = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message);

        // check to see if we can actually record - if we can, assign the event to the button
        string rec = Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureMicrophone;
        if (rec != "android.hardware.microphone")
        {
            // no microphone, no recording. Disable the button and output an alert
            var alert = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(recButton.Context);
            alert.SetTitle("You don't seem to have a microphone to record with");
            alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, e) =>
            {
                textMessage.Text = "No microphone present";
                recButton.Enabled = false;
                return;
            });

            alert.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this);
            mSpeechRecognizer.SetRecognitionListener(this);
            mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
            mSpeechRecognizerIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraCallingPackage, PackageName);
            mSpeechRecognizerIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt, "Start Speaking Now!");
            mSpeechRecognizerIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, this.Resources.Configuration.Locale.Language);
            mSpeechRecognizerIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 5);
            Button StartListening = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRecord);
            StartListening.Click += StartListening_Click;

            RequestPermissionsManually();
        }
    }

    private void RequestPermissionsManually()
    {
            List<string> permission = new List<string>();

            if (CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet) != Permission.Granted)
                permission.Add(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet);

            if (CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio) != Permission.Granted)
                permission.Add(Android.Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio);
            
            if (permission.Count > 0)
            {
                string[] array = permission.ToArray();
                RequestPermissions(array, array.Length);
            }
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
    
    void StartListening_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mSpeechRecognizer.StartListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
    }
    
    public void OnError([GeneratedEnum] SpeechRecognizerError error)
    {
    }

    public void OnResults(Bundle results)
    {
        IList<string> matches = results.GetStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.ResultsRecognition);
    }
}
```

We were originally getting the insufficient privileges error even though we have our permissions manifest setup as follows:

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
>
> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

We added the code to manually request the permissions which moved us on from the InsufficientPermissions error to the Network error in the SpeechRecognizerError enum.

We are running this on Visual studio and Xamarin versions:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017  Version 15.8.8
> VisualStudio.15.Release/15.8.8+28010.2048 Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.7.03056
>
> Xamarin   4.11.0.776 (d15-8@1ae9b59d7) Visual Studio extension to
> enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin Designer   4.15.9 (d000f568b) Visual Studio extension to
> enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin Templates   1.1.116 (9619170) Templates for building iOS,
> Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   9.0.0.19 (HEAD/a8a3b0ec7) Xamarin.Android
> Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.0.0.15 (84552a4) Xamarin.iOS and
> Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

We are running this on the emulator: Android_Accelerated_x86_ORea (Android 8.1 - API 27).

Is there something simple we are missing as to why we are getting this Network error?

Update:
I have now tried the maps application and chrome within the emulator and when selecting the microphone the same problem occurs and it doesn't work.  This appears to be the microphone on the emulator, is there a setting that needs to be enabled?

Comment: Sounds like the emulator you are running can not reach the Google servers (i.e. no internet access), or the emulator does not have the Play services installed, or there is not a "Preferred Engine" assigned in the System Settings

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, if I open chrome on the emulator it works fine and if we deploy the app to an android device it works as well, just appears to be the emulator where it is failing.